# Alternative method of getting Sim number if getLine1Number() returns null

Tags: java, android, telephonymanager

I have written an app which sends a message to a number if the sim card of the phone is changed in other words if the phone number of the phone is changed. The code is working fine on android emulator but when I run this app on my phone, `getLine1Number()` of `TelephonyManager` class is returning null string.

Is there any other way to check if the sim card of the phone is changed?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use getSimOperatorName() concat to getSimSerialNumber() or getSimSerialNumber() only as phone number alternative.
Is more ease to detect sim changes in this way.